# Finding date of particular day between two dates PHP

Tags: php

I have start date and end date.
I also have particular day i.e. wednesday.

Now i want to show date of every wednesday between start date and end date.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function getAllWednesday($from_date, $to_date){
    // getting number of days between two date range.
    $number_of_days = count_days(strtotime($from_date),strtotime($to_date));

    for($i = 1; $i<=$number_of_days; $i++){
        $day = Date('l',mktime(0,0,0,date('m'),date('d')+$i,date('y')));
        if($day == 'wednesday'){
            echo Date('d-m-Y',mktime(0,0,0,date('m'),date('d')+$i,date('y'))),'<br/>';
        }
    }
}
```

The count_days() function

```
function count_days( $a, $b )
{
    // First we need to break these dates into their constituent parts:
    $gd_a = getdate( $a );
    $gd_b = getdate( $b );
    // Now recreate these timestamps, based upon noon on each day
    // The specific time doesn't matter but it must be the same each day
    $a_new = mktime( 12, 0, 0, $gd_a['mon'], $gd_a['mday'], $gd_a['year'] );
    $b_new = mktime( 12, 0, 0, $gd_b['mon'], $gd_b['mday'], $gd_b['year'] );
    // Subtract these two numbers and divide by the number of seconds in a
    // day. Round the result since crossing over a daylight savings time
    // barrier will cause this time to be off by an hour or two.
    return round( abs( $a_new - $b_new ) / 86400 );
}
```

Comment: Is `count_days` a native function I don't know about, or is it assumed the OP must write that part himself?

Comment: Sorry but it does not show dates of days between start date and end date instead it shows days from current date unto no. of times

Comment: @mann and Josh I Edited the answer, and added the count_days() function. Sorry, I saw your problem and I was at the same time working on this. :)