# Get day names between two date in PHP

Tags: php

How to get name of days between two dates in PHP?

**Input:**

> Start Date:  01-01-2013
> End date:    05-01-2013

**Output:**

> Tuesday
> Wednesday
> Thursday
> Friday
> Saturday

**Tried code**

```
$from_date ='01-01-2013';
$to_date ='05-01-2013';

$number_of_days = count_days(strtotime($from_date),strtotime($to_date));

for($i = 1; $i<=$number_of_days; $i++)
{
    $day = Date('l',mktime(0,0,0,date('m'),date('d')+$i,date('y')));
    echo "<br>".$day;       
}


function count_days( $a, $b )
{       
    $gd_a = getdate( $a );
    $gd_b = getdate( $b );
    
    $a_new = mktime( 12, 0, 0, $gd_a['mon'], $gd_a['mday'], $gd_a['year'] );
    $b_new = mktime( 12, 0, 0, $gd_b['mon'], $gd_b['mday'], $gd_b['year'] );
    
    return round( abs( $a_new - $b_new ) / 86400 );
}
```

I saw the post [Finding date of particular day between two dates PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10015136/finding-date-of-particular-day-between-two-dates-php)

But I don't got my result
Please help me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `DateTime` class, it will be much more simple:

```
$from_date ='01-01-2013';
$to_date ='05-01-2013';

$from_date = new DateTime($from_date);
$to_date = new DateTime($to_date);

for ($date = $from_date; $date <= $to_date; $date->modify('+1 day')) {
  echo $date->format('l') . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Simple solution @xdazz great

Answer (score 3):

```
$from_date ='01-01-2013';
$to_date ='05-01-2013';
$start = strtotime($from_date);
$end = strtotime($to_date);
$day = (24*60*60);
for($i=$start; $i<= $end; $i+=86400)
    echo date('l', $i);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    function printDays($from, $to) {
        $from_date=strtotime($from);
        $to_date=strtotime($to);
        $current=$from_date;
        while($current<=$to_date) {
            $days[]=date('l', $current);
            $current=$current+86400;
        }

        foreach($days as $key=> $day) {
            echo $day."\n";
        }
    }
    $from_date ='01-01-2013';
    $to_date ='05-01-2013';
    printDays($from_date, $to_date);
?>
```

Loop through every day between the given dates (inclusive) and then add the corresponding day in an array, using `date` function. Print out the array and tada! you're done!