# How to get Day Name from date in PHP?

Tags: php, datepicker, jquery-validate, weekday

How to get Day Name from date in PHP?

```
$dateValue='2015/07/15';
$dayName=date("D", strtotime($dateValue);
```

Hi,
I want exact day name from the above given sample date, please help me.

Comment: Also there is an error in the code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get day names between two date in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14619682/get-day-names-between-two-date-in-php)

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `l` as the first parameter.

`echo date('l', strtotime($dateValue));`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following code,

```
echo date('l', strtotime($dateValue));
```

for more details, refer following link:

> http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date.asp